# Time calculation in php (add 10 hours)?

Tags: php, time, addition

I get the time:

```
$today = time();
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today));
```

if the current time is "1:00:00 am", how do i add 10 more hours to become 11:00:00 am??

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`strtotime()` gives you a number back that represents a time in seconds. To increment it, add the corresponding number of seconds you want to add. 10 hours = 60*60*10 = 36000, so...

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today)+36000); // $today is today date
```

Edit: I had assumed you had a string time in $today - if you're just using the current time, even simpler:

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', time()+36000); // time() returns a time in seconds already
```

Comment: +1 for a more elegant solution than adding `+ 10 hours` to `strtotime` :)

Comment: $today = time();
echo date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today)+36000);

resut: 10:00:00 am, my localtime is 3.13pm now

Comment: @myphpsql00: That's because `time()` returns a time value in seconds already. Not entirely sure why you're passing `time()` to `strtotime()` - just use `time()` w/o `strtotime()` instead if you're just using the current time. I assumed (because I only glanced at the OP) that you had an actual string time in $today.

Comment: what if i had specific date and time? lets say 28 october 2009, 1:00:00 am? $date = date('h:i:s A', date('28-10-2009 1:00:00')+36000);??

Comment: nvr mind.. I solved the problem, using your method. Thanks Dav

Comment: -1 The only way to do time calculation is `DateTime` as mentioned by @RC. Everything else will get you into trouble eventually.

Comment: You can put $today="now" for computation.

Answer (score 23):

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime($today, $tz);
$date->modify('+10 hours');
// use $date->format() to outputs the result.
```

see [DateTime Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)

Answer (score 8):

### You can simply make use of the [**`DateTime`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) class , OOP Style.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('1:00:00');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT10H'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s a'); //"prints" 11:00:00 a.m
```

Answer (score 7):

`$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today . ' + 10 hours'));`

(untested)

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today . " +10 hours"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Full code that shows now and 10 minutes added.....

```
$nowtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $nowtime;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($nowtime . ' + 10 minute'));
echo "<br>".$date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase or decrease time using [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you could use a [Relative format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) in the first argument.

In your case to increase the *current time* by 10 hours:

```
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime('+10 hours'));
```

In case you need to apply the change to another timestamp, the second argument can be specified.

**Note:**

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use [`DateTime::add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

So, **the recommended way** since PHP 5.3:

```
$dt = new DateTime(); // assuming we need to add to the current time
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT10H'));
$date = $dt->format('h:i:s A');
```

or using aliases:

```
$dt = date_create(); // assuming we need to add to the current time
date_add($dt, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 hours')); 
$date = date_format($dt, 'h:i:s A');
```

In all cases the default time zone will be used unless a time zone is specified.